# How many foes can you hit in melee at the same time

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I swing my hammer while being surrounded by foes, I *think* I might be hitting more than 5 at a time, which is meant to be the global area damage cap, but the numbers go away too fast for me to count them.

I know most skills are meant to be capped at 5 targets, but does the same apply do melee?

Comment: Could you please inform what skill are you using?

Comment: I'm mainly thinking about my Guardian's hammer chain.

Comment: It is possible that if you have 6 foes on the screen, the first strike is hitting 1,2,3,4,5 and then the second swing hits 1,2,3,4,6. The 5 damage indicator may still be fading as the second swing hits. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [recent statement by a programmer](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/pvp/wuvwuv/Siege-Weapons-and-AOE-Limits/first#post1213795), all player skills are capped at 5 targets.

> As we’ve previously said, the AOE target limit on player skills is currently set to 5. That means that any given player skill will hit at most 5 players regardless of how many players are in the area of the skill.